# What is a casual and tangible term for generalizing?

Tags: single-word-requests, colloquialisms

What is a casual and tangible term for generalizing?

For example,

> Don't [generalise] your experience thinking that others have the same.

So far I have found "assume" which is good, but I was wondering if there is an even more casual, tangible, and colloquial word for it.

Edit: I think *project* and *generalize* make sense but I would like a more colloquial phrase for that if available as if I am talking to a friend.

To explain further, let's assume that John and Julie are working at a company. Julie says something that implies John also is making low money like Julie. Then, John says:

> How are you so sure I am also making low money? Don't generalize/project your experience to others.

Comment: Do you think that the meaning of extrapolating experience is clear? What do you mean by that? You may *extrapolate on the basis of your experience*;  that makes sense. Do you mean "to make up your experience"? I don't think you can say it like that. It seems to me that your question would benefit from explaining what you mean.

Comment: You are misusing extrapolate in your example.

Comment: You could rephrase it such as "Don't assume everybody's the same as you". But you're not going to get a synonym for extrapolation here (there are some colloquial phrases for extrapolation in time, "if this goes on" etc, but not for overgeneralisation over entities like this).

Comment: Could you please explain what you mean by "tangible"

Comment: None of this generalize or experiencing reads like English to me. What do you mean by "your experience" — near death, childhood in the Andes, battered wife? If you tell me I can translate it into the sort of English my mother would have used.

Comment: I would believe everyone believes to some extent their experiences are not too different from others. The phenomenon has been called "false consensus effect" or "similar-to-me effect".

Answer (score 4):

You probably mean

> Do not ***project*** your experience onto others.

***Project*** here means

> to wrongly imagine that someone else is feeling a particular emotion or desire when in fact it is you who feels this way:
>
> - I suspect he's ***projecting*** his fears onto you. ([Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/project))

For something more colloquial, you could use [Damian Barr](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Damian_Barr)'s quote:

> ***We are not all in the same boat.***

This is a reversal of the idiom ***to be in the same boat***:

> to be in the same unpleasant situation as other people:
>
> - She's always complaining that she doesn't have enough money, but *we're all in the same boat*.

Answer (score 2):

> Don't **generalize** your experience to others.

**Generalize** (v.)

> To make a general statement that something is true in all cases, based
> on what is true in some cases.
>
> *Dr. Meyer warned against **generalizing** the results to populations not included in the study.* [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/generalize)

> If you **generalize** something such as an idea, you apply it more widely
> than its original context, as if it was true in many other situations.
>
> *A child first labels the household pet cat as a "cat" and then **generalizes** this label to other animals that look like it.*
> [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/generalize)

*Generalize* leaves open the appropriateness/correctness of an act; *overgeneralize* refers to the inappropriateness/inaccuracy of the act.

Comment: This is just to note that the OP changed the question after I posted this answer. The original was "What is a casual and tangible term for **extrapolation**"

Answer (score 0):

> Don't **take for granted** that other people have experienced what you
> have.

[Merriam-Webster defines this phrase](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/take%20for%20granted) in this sense as follows:

> to assume (something) as true, real, unquestionable, or to be expected
>
> We took our invitation to the party for granted. = We took it for
> granted that we'd be invited to the party. [=we assumed we'd be
> invited and did not think about the possibility that we wouldn't be]
>
> What I will call the "old" middle class rose to prominence in the
> Forties, Fifties, and Sixties, when economic growth was taken for
> granted and opportunity was abundant. —Alan Wolfe

This is a phrase that is widely understood, which is in a slightly less formal register than "assume" or "project" and is also less clunky and cerebral than "generalize".

Comment: Thank you for the comment, but I don't think "Don't take for granted that other people have experienced what you have." has the same meaning as "Don't [generalise] your experience thinking that others have the same."